# sql errors, Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql

I try to write a php file to insert the data to my table, but when I run the code in SQL, it is give me these errors. I think I need to use AND or OR, but I am so confused. Anyone can help me with it? Thank you.

1.This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "FROM" at position 610)

2.Unrecognized statement type. (near "FROM" at position 610)

```
 INSERT INTO Event(type,game_id,player_id,pass_id) 
            SELECT '$array[5]', G.gid 
            FROM Game G 
            WHERE G.date='$array[4]' 
            AND teamone_id=(SELECT tid 
                            FROM Team 
                            WHERE teamName='$array[2]' 
                            OR  teamName='$array[3]')
            AND teamtwo_id=(SELECT tid 
                            FROM Team 
                            WHERE teamName='$array[2]' 
                            OR  teamName='$array[3]'), 
            pid FROM Player WHERE first='$array[0]' AND last ='$array[1]', 
            pid FROM Player WHERE first='$array[0]' AND last ='$array[1]' AND '$array[5]'='passing'
```

I edit my code after these error, and I do not know if it is correct. And I got error: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Here is my code after edit:

```
INSERT INTO Event(type,game_id,player_id,pass_id) 
    SELECT 'passing', g1.gid, p1.pid, p2.pid 
    FROM Game AS g1, Player AS p1 JOIN Player AS p2
    WHERE g1.date='2010-09-12' 
    AND teamone_id=(SELECT t1.tid,t2.tid 
                    FROM Team AS t1
                    CROSS JOIN Team AS t2
                    WHERE t1.teamName='Seattle' 
                    AND  t2.teamName='NewEngland')
    AND teamtwo_id=(SELECT t1.tid,t2.tid 
                    FROM Team AS t1
                    CROSS JOIN Team AS t2
                    WHERE t1.teamName='Seattle' 
                    AND  t2.teamName='NewEngland')
    AND t1.first='Doug' AND t2.last ='Baldwin'
    AND t2.first='Russell' AND t2.last ='Wilson' AND '$array[5]'='passing'
```

Comment: You can't have multiple WHERE clauses. It looks like you're trying to get a cross product, you need to use a self-JOIN.

Comment: I used JOIN for my code that I posted, but I have trouble that how to fill in all four columns?

Comment: One or more of your subqueries are returning more than one result.  Try adding `DISTINCT` to the beginning of each of the `SELECT t1.tid,t2.tid` subqueries.  If that doesn't work, run the queries by themselves to see what the results are.

Comment: .. Or change the subqueries to `AND teamone_id IN` rather than `=`